# setting hibernate.max_fetch_depth in spring petclinic

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am experimenting with the spring petclinic app, the complete code for which is [at this link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic).  I would like to set `hibernate.max_fetch_depth=0`, but I cannot seem to get this setting to take effect when I re-start tomcat server and re-launch the app from eclipse.

Here is [a link to the directory that contains all the config files](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic/tree/master/src/main/resources/spring).  **In which config file should I place the `hibernate.max_fetch_depth=0` setting, and what exact syntax should I use?**

I tried placing this in `business-config.xml`:

```
<property name="jpaProperties">
     <props>
        <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</prop>
        <prop key="hibernate.max_fetch_depth">0</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

I also tried putting this in `data-access.properties`:

```
 hibernate.max_fetch_depth=0
```

But neither approach seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I set it in one of my tests in [GitHub](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-master-class/blob/master/core/src/test/java/com/vladmihalcea/hibernate/masterclass/laboratory/util/AbstractTest.java):

```
properties.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", "0");
```

Then I debbuged the SessionFactory class:

```
Integer maxFetchDepth = ConfigurationHelper.getInteger( AvailableSettings.MAX_FETCH_DEPTH, properties );
if ( maxFetchDepth != null ) {
    LOG.debugf( "Maximum outer join fetch depth: %s", maxFetchDepth );
}
settings.setMaximumFetchDepth( maxFetchDepth );
```

And it worked perfectly:

```
DEBUG [main]: o.h.c.SettingsFactory - Maximum outer join fetch depth: 0
```

Try defining it in persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="0"/>
</properties>
```

Comment: Did you manage to find why it didn't work in the first place?

Comment: Excessive inheritance caused the problem. You stated this in your answer to the root question. I ended up flattening part of the schema to reduce the number of tables included in joins.  Thank you for following up.

Comment: I have another hibernate question.  Are you willing to help me with it also?  Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640195/unidirectional-many-to-one-relationship-with-inheritance

Answer (score 1):

I created `hibernate.properties` file and placed it under `src/main/resources`.

Added following entry to the property file and restarted the server:

`max_fetch_depth=3`

From the logs I could validate that the property has been set in the hibernate configurations.